# Data Structure for Positioning Non-Overlapping Rectangles Into Grid

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm trying to implement a very crude form of the css grid layout. It's layout algorithm is as [documented](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#auto-placement-algo).

> “sparse” packing (default behavior)
> Set the column-start line of its placement to the earliest (smallest positive index) line index that ensures this item’s grid area will not overlap any occupied grid cells and that is past any grid items previously placed in this row by this step.

Is there an efficient data structure to calculate the next available position of a grid rectangle given a list of existing grid rectangles? I've thought about using a 2D Interval Tree but can't find any good references on extending from 1D to 2D.

Comment: I think it'll make sense if you give us a precise mathematical formulation of the "css grid layout" problem. Not just a reference to it...

Comment: Not sure if there's a precise mathematical formulation; just whether there's a faster way than brute forcing finding available space. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683169/how-to-find-open-rectangle-with-specific-size-efficiently